# Erro quando tento Adicionar MVC Controller com views, usando Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, controller

Olá, quando tento criar um Controller dá o erro anexo. Alguém sabe do como resolver? Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: isso parece ser alguma incompatibilidade do package com o framework do core. Já viu se a versão do Core que está usando é compatível com o package do Mysql.Data.EntityframeworkCore?

Comment: Agora que vi aqui, o pacote Mysql.Data.EntityframeworkCore foi descontinuado. Acho que foi isso. E agora não sei como fazer.